# yolov5 not training on custom dataset

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, object-detection, yolov5, custom-training

I am using yolov5 to train on custom dataset
my dataset.yaml file contains

```
path: ../testing
train: images
val: images
nc: 10
names:
  ["door", "cabinetDoor", "refrigeratorDoor", "window", "chair",
  "table", "cabinet", "couch", "openedDoor", "pole"]
```

The directory of dataset is as follows

```
CustomTraining
├── yolov5
├── testing
    ├── images
    │   ├── train  (1024 images)
    │   └── val    (230 images )
    └── labels
        ├── train
        └── val
```

command I run is

```
!cd yolov5 && python train.py --img 512 --batch 10 --epoch 100 --data dataset.yml --weights yolov5s.pt
```

but when I see my runs/train directory in yolov5 folder the exp folders does not have any jpeg files and weights folders are also empty

Comment: As provided output . You have set the current directory to Yolov5 and run the training script . Now the script is looking for the testing directory  in yolv5 folder. Provide the absolute path in data.yaml file or move the directory in yolov5 folder.

Answer (score 0):

It been a long time，dont know whether u have solved the problem.
sry that Im not capabale to embed pictures here

**1:First**, try to change the relative path in the yaml file into absolute path.

**2:Second**，In fact,here is my doc,you can have try at this.

**yaml file:**

```yaml
train: D:\yolov5\datasets\mydata\ImageSets\Main\train.txt
 
 
val: D:\yolov5\datasets\mydata\ImageSets\Main\train.txt
 
test:  # test images (optional)
```

**directory：**

```
 - **D:\yolov5**    
    - yolov5-7.0(main project)
       - train.py
       - detect.py
       - .......
    - **datasets**(place I store my datas)
       - coco128
         - iamges 
         - labels
         - readme
       - **mydata**
         - images(my pictures to train)
            - IMG_000001.jpg
            - IMG_000002.jpg
            - IMG_000003.jpg
            ......
         - labels(labels for my pictures)
            - IMG_000001.txt
            - IMG_000002.txt
            - IMG_000003.txt
            ......
         - **ImageSets**
           - **Main**
             - **train.txt**
```

**train.txt:**

**You need to put the path of *this folder*  in the yaml file,yolov5 will scan this file to find your images and labels,!!!!!！！！！！！！**
You might doubt that this txt file is neither "images.txt" nor "labels.txt", then how does the model find the datasets they need.

**So here is the content of the train.txt**

```
 D:\yolov5\datasets\mydata\**images**\IMG_000001.jpg 
 D:\yolov5\datasets\mydata\**images**\IMG_000002.jpg 
 ......
```

Yes , you can see that the content of of this "train.txt" is exactly just the **absolute path of the pictures that you want to train!!!**

Now , you might want to ask again, "what about my labels?"
**The code in yolov5 will turn the word "images" in the absolute path mentioned above "D:\yolov5\datasets\mydata\images\IMG_000001.jpg" into "labels" automatically to find your labels file.** So you dont need to mention your labelfile's path in this file. **And that is exactly why you need to organize your directory like that.** And remeber to change the name of your "labels.txt" into "IMG_000001"(just be the same as your images name is OK,"IMG_00000n" is my project name, you dont have to be like that) ,so it can find your labels with the path after changing "images" into "labels" ,
like"D:\yolov5\datasets\mydata\ **labels** \IMG_000001.jpg"

**Hope I can make it clear to you guys . Thanks 4 wathcing.**

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
train: /content/drive/MyDrive/Classes/YOLOv8/data/train/images
val: /content/drive/MyDrive/Classes/YOLOv8/data/valid/images

# Classes
names:
  0: drug
```

In `coco128.yml`  to change the datasets path only pass the path of images cannot pass the image file pass the image folder path